# Are ConcurrentDictionary's Keys and Values properties thread-safe?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

From the `ConcurrentDictionary`'s API, I see that its enumerator is thread-safe, but I don't see the same for `Keys` and `Values` properties.

Is it safe to loop over the `Keys` or `Values` collection when there are other threads modifying it concurrently?

Comment: The enumerator behaves differently from the Keys and Values properties. While those provide a moment-in-time snapshot of the dictionary, the contents  returned by [`GetEnumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287131.aspx)(which is also used in LINQ queries that use the dictionary as source) contain modifications made to the dictionary after `GetEnumerator` was called.

Comment: ConcurrentDictionary Is Not Always Thread-Safe - http://blog.i3arnon.com/2018/01/16/concurrent-dictionary-tolist/ .

Comment: I see two different activities here: 1 - getting the reference to collection from dictionary (it may be not atomic), 2 - enumeration through collection. Is it possible that other threads will be modifying dictionary when the thread under question will be trying to retrieve the collection for enumeration.

Answer (score 60):

While I do like the documentation, I tend to verify things with a small program when in doubt or I feel that I might be assuming too much.

The following code verifies that indeed you can enumerate the values collection safely while adding or removing keys from a separate thread to that on which the enumeration is taking place. This will not cause the usual collection was modified exceptions. In more detail, here are a couple of test cases

**Case 1: Enumerating Values and deleting a key**

If you follow the following sequence:

- start enumerating the values collection from a thread
- remove a key from a different thread that we have not enumerated yet
- Continue enumerating on the original thread

The observed behavior is that the removed key will indeed be enumerated since it existed in the values collection when we started the enumeration. No exception will be raised.

**Case 2: Enumerating Values and adding a key**

- start enumerating the values collection from a thread
- add a new key from a different thread that we have not enumerated yet
- Continue enumerating on the original thread

The observed behavior is that the added key will not be enumerated since it did not exist in values collection when we started to enumerate it. No exception will be raised whether we use TryAdd or add by assigning directly to the dictionary ie dictionary[key] = value.

**Sample Code**

Here is the sample program that demonstrates both cases:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<int, int> dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();

// Seed the dictionary with some arbitrary values; 
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    dictionary.TryAdd(i, i);
}

// Reader thread - Enumerate the Values collection
Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () =>
        {
            foreach (var item in dictionary.Values)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Item {0}: count: {1}", item, dictionary.Count);
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }

        }
);

// writer thread - Modify dictionary by adding new items and removing existing ones from the end
Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () =>
        {
            for (int i = 29; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                //Remove an existing entry 
                int removedValue;
                if (dictionary.TryRemove(i, out removedValue))
                    Console.WriteLine("Removed item {0}", removedValue);
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Did not remove item {0}", i);

                int iVal = 50 + i*2;
                dictionary[iVal] = iVal;
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                iVal++;
                dictionary.TryAdd(iVal, iVal);
            }
        }
);

Console.ReadKey();
```

And here is the **output in release mode**:

[image: Console output]

Comment: Wish microsoft could document this in MSDN.

Comment: What you're really saying is the the `Keys` and `Values` collections are snapshots of the dictionary at the time when you obtained the enumerator.  Almost like they did a deep clone and handed it back to you to enumerate over.

Comment: This experiment doesn't cover everything. And may be misleading. There is more than one problem here. First of all it doesn't check what exactly happens when `ConcurrentDictionary` generates the collection of values for the property caller. Even more, the documentation explicitly states that "Read operations on the dictionary are performed in a lock-free manner." (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2). It means that when one thread will be generating keys or values snapshot the other one may change the dictionary content.

Comment: Another more general problem with such kind of experiments can lead to really wrong conclusions. If some specific framework implementation behaves somehow in one experiment it does NOT mean that it will behave the same in another framework version if it is not explicitly "guaranteed" by documentation.

Comment: I guess the actual main problem with this test code is that `Task` is NOT necessarily a (different) thread. Therefore, APIs such as `Task.Factory.StartNew()` must never be used to test multi-threading\concurrency stuff. Depending on a Task Scheduler, those methods could be run on the SAME thread. So unfortunately, this code couldn't be a proof for the real concurrent environment. You need to spawn real bare threads, not `Task`s.

Answer (score 16):

> ConcurrentDictionary Represents a **thread-safe** collection of key-value
>   pairs that can be accessed by multiple threads concurrently.

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx)

Comment: +1, concise! :) Addition: yes, both properties are protected with a lock, what you'll enumerate is the content of the dictionary **at the moment you started the enumeration** (so you may see a key, for example, that has been deleted from another thread).

Answer (score 12):

Yes, its threadsafe. *But*, even though it is threadsafe you should prefer NOT to to use `Keys`, `Values`, and also `Count`.

Especially so when you are using `ConcurrentCollections<T>` because you want to minimize lock contention, blocking of threads, and allocation of memory. And you do want those things if you care about performance and efficiency.

Look at the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs.html) to see why - `Keys` immediately calls a `GetKeys()` helper and that *takes every single lock* before continuing. Once it has the locks, it copies *every single key* into a `new List<TKey>`, and returns a readonly view of that -- just so someone cannot accidentally mutate what is really just a temporary copy of the keys collection. This requires allocating quite large arrays, and holding the locks for quite some time, if your collection got large!

`Values` locks and copies every single value similarly to `Keys`. Even `Count` acquires all locks, not in order to copy, in order to sum up all the internal table segment lengths. All just to get a momentarily 'consistent' count of objects in the collection, which is useful only as a rough estimate or historical footnote once the lock is released.

So yes, *sigh*, if you need atomic consistency I suppose this may be the price you have to pay. But! Perhaps you are luckier than that. You then might realize consistency is not actually required for your scenario, and that much more performant APIs to those bad ones are within your grasp - like using `GetEnumerator()` to get an approximate idea of what items are in your collection instead! The remark in `GetEnumerator()`'s docs:

> The enumerator returned from the dictionary is safe to use
> concurrently with reads and writes to the dictionary, however it does
> not represent a moment-in-time snapshot of the dictionary.  The
> contents exposed through the enumerator may contain modifications made
> to the dictionary after GetEnumerator was called.

In other words, it doesn't need to lock or copy at all because it doesn't need to ensure consistency. Hooray!

Comment: I just discovered a rather horrifying bug when using LINQ on `ConcurrentDictionary`, so be careful when using the enumerator: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/48805.

Comment: @MikeMarynowski Great example of how you should not use ConcurrentDictionary enumerator with LINQ.