# How to maintain static Dictionary for atomic operation in multithreading C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure-functions, semaphore

I have been using azure-function which is time-based. 
I want to achieve multithreading for batch processing in my function app. 
The instances of azure function are created every 10 seconds.
I have been managing a static dictionary which is having batchId and batchStatus(i.e "Added", "Processed", "Failed")
Here is the sample code

```
static Dictionary<string, string> processedFiles = new Dictionary<string, string>();

 public static async void Run([TimerTrigger(" */5 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
                string fileToBeProcessed = processedFiles.Where(x => x.Value == "Added").Select(x => x.Key).SingleOrDefault();
                processedFiles[fileToBeProcessed] = "Processing";

                bool g = BatchProcessFiles(fileToBeProcessed); //Here i am working on the processing of batch

                if(g == true)
                    processedFiles[fileToBeProcessed] = "Completed";
                else
                    processedFiles[fileToBeProcessed] = "Error";


}
```

It works properly in most of the cases. Any instance would push new batches id into a dictionary with status "Added".

It would take any id which is "Added" and mark it as "Processed" and would start working on it.

The problem what I face is this:

If there is a case where two or more instances are reading the same id in a dictionary at the same time, they both would find its value "Added" and they both would pick that up. Ultimately one would process the batch successfully but other instances won't find that batch and would fall into error.

is there anything like a lock that I can implement over the dictionary every time I read and write it?

Comment: Dictionary is not a thread safe data structure in C#. Instead, you could use [ConcurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, if you are working with multi thread and using a Dictionary, you will end up with issues in C#.

This is because Dictionary is not a thread-safe data structure.

Instead, you should be using [ConcurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8)

If that's what you are looking for, I would advice you to have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479867/is-concurrentdictionary-keys-or-values-property-threadsafe)

Hoping it will help you.